# How to consume wso2 identity server rest services in my spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to consume one of the rest service in wso2
`"https://localhost:9443/api/identity/recovery/v0.9/recover-password?type=email&notify=false"` using rest template. But I am getting below exception

> `org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://localhost:9443/api/identity/recovery/v0.9/recover-password": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:744)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:579)
>           at com.diligent.cdd.master.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.getWSO2ResetPWDKey(UserServiceImpl.java:49)
>           at com.diligent.cdd.master.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.resetUserPwd(UserServiceImpl.java:43)
>           at com.diligent.cdd.master.controllers.UserController.resetUserPassword(UserController.java:26)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)`

I have tried enabling ssl properties in my application by below,

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:wso2carbon.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=wso2carbon
server.ssl.key-alias=wso2carbon
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened because WSO2 Identity server expects the certificate of the application during SSL handshake and the certificate of the application is missing in the truststore. So what you have to do is,

1. Import the application's SSL public certificate into Identity Server's client-truststore.jks. It is located in /repository/resources/security/ folder.
2. You can use the following command to import into the client-truststore.

> keytool -importcert -alias  -file 
>   -keystore ${IS_HOME}/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
>   -storepass wso2carbon -noprompt

3. Restart the server.

You can refer this [blog](http://evanthika.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-solve-pkix-path-building-failed.html). 
Hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: I think the error is coming in the spring boot application side. If so you have to import the public certificate of the Identity Server to the spring boot application side.